# Laravel doesn't give the correct locale in web.php

Tags: php, laravel

My app can change locale using url request.

```
Route::get('/setLocale/{locale}', function (Request $request, $locale) {
    session()->put('locale', $locale);
    App::setLocale($locale);
    return redirect('/');
})->name('setLocale');
```

And that locale string would be stored in session. I use middleware to dynamically change locale using the session data if there's any.

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if (session('locale')) {
            App::setLocale(session('locale'));
        }
        return $next($request);
    }
```

The problem is that `App::getLocale()` in `web.php` always return default locale settings, even when the locale is set to the other one (because I can see different text on web).

```
$locale = App::getLocale();

dd($locale); // default locale set in config.php
```

I tried using `session('locale')`, but it always return `null`. I am pretty sure it's set in session because I can see the website has that locale.

The reason I need reference of locale is because I want to generate dynamic route prefix based on locale.

```
$locale = App::getLocale();

Route::prefix($locale)->group(function () {
   ....
});
```

I am wondering what's the problem here? Is it because session isn't instantiated before routes?

---

Kernal.php

```
protected $middlewareGroups = [
        'web' => [
            ... (default)
            \App\Http\Middleware\SetLocale::class,
        ],
    ];
```

So I dd() the App::getLocale() on web.php and on my globle web middleware, dd() on web.php gets printed first...

So I get web.php is called before any global middlewares are registerd. But then how can I set dynamic prefix based on locale???

Comment: check this out, https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/session-doesnt-work-in-middleware .

Comment: @Wreigh, the problem is not setting the locale in the middleware, because it works in my case. The problem is that I can't get session('locale') or the correct value of App::getLocale() in web.php...

Comment: have you read it? the question there seems to have the same nature as with your problem.

Comment: did you see this already https://mydnic.be/post/laravel-5-and-his-fcking-non-persistent-app-setlocale? where do you call `App::getLocale()`? is that inside a route group with the above middleware?

Comment: @Wreigh App::getLocale(); is not in any route function, it's at the "outermost" scope of the web.php. Not in any function... Because I need define this variable in the global scope, only then I can set dynamic prefix.

Comment: then what's happening is normal, because based from what I've read, `App::setLocale()` is non persistent, thus the locale will be set back to its original on the next request. Because you are **setting** the locale inside the middleware and you are calling `App::getLocale()` in the global scope of `web.php` (Yes, before the middleware was even called). may I see your *Kernel.php* file? (where middlewares are registered)

Comment: can you `dd` inside your middleware and on where you call `App::getLocale()`? Let's just see who gets fired first. if the one where `App::getLocale()` is called gets fired first, then my assumption is right.

Comment: @Wreigh dd() on web.php called first..

Answer (score 4):

You can use something like this

here is the routes

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['language']], function () {
   Route::get('/language/{locale}', [
    'uses' => 'Frontend\LanguageController@changeLanguage',
    'as' => 'language.changer',
    'role' => ['company', 'user']
   ]);
});
```

here is the language controller

```
<?php

 namespace App\Http\Controllers\Frontend;
 use Illuminate\Http\Request;
 use App\Http\Controllers\Controller; 
 use Session;

class LanguageController extends Controller
{
public function changeLanguage($locale){
    Session::put('locale', $locale);
    return redirect()->back();
}
}
```

this is the middleware

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    if (Session::has('locale') == true) {

        App::setLocale(Session::get('locale'));
    }
    Carbon::setLocale(Session::get('locale'));
    return $next($request);
}
```

and this to set up your default locale if something went wrong

```
public function boot()
{
    Schema::defaultStringLength(191);
    if(Session::has('locale') == false)
    {
        App::setLocale('en');
    }
}
```

finally you can use something like that :

```
<li class="is-relative hidden-lg hidden-md">
   <a href="/logout">
      <i class="fa fa-power-off"></i> 
      {{ trans('lang.logout') }}
     <span class="sr-only">(current)</span>
  </a>
</li>
```

hope this helps you ..

Comment: this is exactly what is in the link that I've shared.

Comment: @Wreigh Maybe look at flagging then.

Comment: yes, this should work :) @GrantGarrison no need, I just stated that lol, thank you!

Comment: @Wreigh oh I thought he "stole" your answer when you were about to post it or something like that.

Comment: Instead of if else block in controller how is written for now, just line `Session::put('locale', $locale);` would work the same way.

Answer (score 1):

You can **set** and **get** the locale application using this global helper in your **web.php** file:

```
<?php

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Web Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register web routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
| contains the "web" middleware group. Now create something great!
|
*/
app()->setLocale('en');
dd(app()->getLocale());
```

But your middleware will be applied **after** you request access some route not **before**.
So, to test your app locale put this code `dd(app()->getLocale())` inside your controller.

This should work.

Comment: It always return the default one. Even my global web middle has set it to other locale.